# Facebook Permissions for mobile application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

i want to publish images from mobile app to server,server to Facebook. what are the steps needed to get approval from facebook?

```
Note: 
1 ) MobileApp--->Facebook(Login)
2 ) MobileApp--->Server(Sending AccessToken, UserId, Images, UserComments)
3 ) Server------>FaceBook(For sharing).
```

Am creating mobile applications for both iOS and Android, In which am using Facebook login and share functionalities. Once the user logged-in through facebook i will take the access token and account id from the particular user and saved it into database in my server. On share screen i am showing customized UI for posting images where user can give their own comments,If the user press the share Button i send that Images and user comments to the server,there they will post the images and comments from server directly along with the UserId and AccessToken of that particular user to the facebook. what are the basic steps needed to get the approval from facebook for publish_action?please suggest some ideas...

Comment: Check the documentation for the SDK you're planning on using. It's documented.

Comment: @323go - i checked the documentation. sorry i can't get that. if you don't mine send that link. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The Review Guidelines can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Please refer to them if you have questions concerning the process.